# MySQL table automatically deleted on Restarting Tomcat Server

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, tomcat7

I am building a spring MVC web application. I am using Hibernate as my ORM. Whenever I restart my tomcat 7 server, it automatically deletes the table created previously. How to prevent this?

Comment: You should post a bit more information to get meaningful help on this.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Search for `hbm2ddl` text somewhere in your configuration, close to Hibernate configuration properties. It should be set to `update` or `none`, apparently you have `create-drop`.

## See also

- [Hibernate hbm2ddl.auto possible values and what they do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/438146)